# Map with custom markers + view all Markers

Tags: android

Hi guys I expose my problem, but before I show you the code that I created in order to follow with more detail:

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_map);

            GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (map != null) {
                    // Ciclo un mio ArrayList contenente contenuti con relative Latitudine e Longitudine
                    for (int i = 0; i < Contenuti.size(); i++) {
                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(Contenuti.get(i)
                                            .getLatitude());
                            double lng = Double.parseDouble(Contenuti.get(i)
                                            .getLongitude());

                            LatLng PUNTI = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                            String title = Contenuti.get(i).getName();

                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(POI_POINT).title(title));
                    }

                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(STARTING_POINT, 5));
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

            }

    }
```

I think that so far everything is clear :

1 - Load a map ;

2 - Cycle an ArrayList with all conenuti and associate a marker for each content .

Well come to my request or problem :

1 - Should I , after placing all the markers on the map , you can see the map on the screen that displays all markers created, I saw that for this my cases there is a method " newLatLngBounds " Google Maps to center / display all points and display them on the screen but I do not understand how to integrate it into my code , or rather from the evidence that I made the application must be in error !

2 - The second issue is that I should associate , not in a static manner , the properties of the Marker icon with the image recovered from my ArrayList ( in this case a url containing this image ) ... But that's not all because the image is superimposed or enclosed within my pin.png -> in this case I have seen the use of ' " InfoWindowAdapter " but it is not what I want ! since the latter creates the screen with information on the marker inside my custom layout , to better convey the idea I show you the code that I tried:

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

            private View view;

            public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_pin, null);
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    if (MapActivity.this.marker != null
                                    && MapActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                            MapActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                            MapActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
                    }
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
                    MapActivity.this.marker = marker;

                    String url = null;

                    if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                            if (markers.get(marker.getId()) != null
                                            && markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                                    url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                            }
                    }

                    final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

                    if (url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                                    && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, image);
                    } else {
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    }

                    return view;
            }

    }

    private void initWidget() {
            txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(id.txtHeaderMenu);

            if (Commons.categoriesList != null) {
                    txtHeader.setText(Commons.categoriesList.get(Commons.cat_id)
                                    .getName());
            }

    }
```

I used the external library universalimageloader for displaying images. It works ... but it is not what I want because they are the markers that should take this effect.

Thank you in advance for your cooperation

I await your suggestions ....